# Which is more numerically stable for OLS: pinv vs QR

Tags: matrix, computational-statistics, matrix-decomposition, matrix-inverse

If I am doing standard OLS and want to calculate beta values (OLS estimators), which of the following is the more numerically stable method? And why?

Assuming that the columns of $X$ are already mean-centered and normalised, to solve $Y = X\beta + \epsilon$ do:

1) $\hat{\beta}_{pinv}=(X'X)^+X'Y$

2) $\hat{\beta}_{QR} = \text{solve}(R,Q'Y)$

Where $^+$ represents the moore-penrose inverse, $Q$ and $R$ come from the QR decomposition of $X$ and `solve` is a function like the solve functions in python or r.

I would have thought (2) was better as $(X'X)^+$ seems to have a higher condition number than $R$, but in practice (in python at least) I am finding that the beta values derived from (1) minimize the sum of squared residuals better.

Comment: When you write "minimize the sum of residuals" in your last line, do you mean "minimize the sum of squared residuals"?

Comment: Apologies, yes I do. I will change this now.

Comment: I cannot see why one method would "*minimize the sum of squared residuals better*"... In any case, QR is faster. QR-decomposition should be of order $\frac{4}{3} n^3$ while the SVD (the work-horse behind the MP-pseudo-inverse) takes $\frac{8}{3}n^3$. (For the record, Cholesky is the fastest with $\frac{1}{3}n^3$) You can quickly check [`RcppEigen`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RcppEigen/vignettes/RcppEigen-Introduction.pdf)'s vignette for some timing informaton (check Table 2).

Comment: When you say "computationally efficient" -- per your title and first paragraph -- you seem to be asking about calculation speed (perhaps measured in flops, or by multiplications and additions -- or maybe by some other measure), but the last paragraph of your question talks about *condition number* which seems to imply you're interested in something *other* than speed (in many situations one can get more speed by choosing a less stable algorithm). Can you be clearer about what you want to know?

Comment: I am very sorry yes I was interested in the speed but my main concern was actually numerical stability - sorry to have caused such confusion. I have addressed this now. Thank you for the indepth analysis of the time in flops as well though - this is still greatly valued information and will go a long way in helping me with what I am doing.

Comment: @JDoe2: Thank you for the clarification. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

Using the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse $X^{\dagger}$ of an matrix $X$ is more stable in the sense that can directly account for rank-deficient design matrices $X$. 
$X^{\dagger}$ allows us to naturally employ the identities: $X^{\dagger} X X^{\dagger} = X$ and $X X^{\dagger} X= X^{\dagger}$; the matrix $X^{\dagger}$ can be used as "surrogate" the true inverse of the matrix $X$, even if the inverse matrix $X^{-1}$ does not exist. In addition, the "usual" way of computing $X^{\dagger}$ by employing the Singular Value Decomposition of matrix $X$, where $X = USV^T$, is straight-forward methodologically and computationally well-studied. We simply take the reciprocal of the non-zero singular values in the diagonal matrix $S$, and we are good to go.  Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverses are common in many proofs because they "just exist" and [*greatly simplify many derivations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_involving_the_Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse).

That said, in most cases it is not good practice to use the Moore-Penrose Pseudo-inverse unless we have a very good reason (e.g. our procedure consistently employs  small and potentially rank-degenerate covariance matrices). The reasons are that: 1. It can hide true underlying problems with our data (e.g. duplication of variables) and 2. it is unnecessarily expensive (we have better alternatives). Finally, note that the  Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of a full rank $X$ can be directed computed through the QR factorization of $X$, $X = QR$, as: $X^{\dagger} = [R^{-1}_{1} 0] Q^T$ where $R_1$ is an upper triangular matrix, coming from the "thin/reduced/skinny" QR factorization of $X$. So we do not really gain much if $X$ is full rank anyway. (Gentle's [Matrix Algebra: Theory, Computations and Applications in Statistics](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Matrix-Algebra-Computations-Applications-Statistics/dp/3319648667) provides a wealth of information the matter if one wishes to explore this further - Sect. 3.6 on *Generalised Inverses* should be a relevant starting point.)

To elaborate my first point a bit: It is far more natural to use a penalised regression procedure like Ridge or LASSO if we have issues with collinearity or simply have a $p\gg n$ (i.e. more predictors than data-points) than hide the problem using $X^\dagger$. The condition of a system of equations solved through the employment of Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverses might still be prohibitorily  bad, resulting to unstable solutions and/or misleading inference. Thus if numerical stability is an issue, I would suggest using regularisation directly instead of Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverses. Note that in terms of speed, computing $X^{\dagger}$ is also problematic; potentially iterative methods based on gradient descent methods or alternating least squares are far faster for large systems (e.g. in Recommender Systems literature, see Paterek (2008) *[Improving regularized singular value decomposition for collaborative filtering](https://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/KDD-cup-2007/proceedings/Regular-Paterek.pdf)* for something very concise).

Comment: Thank you for the in detail response. I shall make note to look at these references and take on what you had described!

Comment: this is helpful. so Moore-Penrose is capable of generating solutions even if the kernel is rank deficient, which is often a good thing, but could accidentally be bad by hiding numerical problems by that same capability. Computational cost is rarely a concern for my uses.

QR factorization generates the least-squares solution (which pseudoinverse does also) when X is full rank but is less costly.

I'm still a fan of the Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse. It's an amazing result.